# GStreamer - change resolution for RSTP stream

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, flv

It works to convert RTSP stream to flv stream, but I can't change resolution using below command

```
gst-launch-1.0  rtspsrc location=$RTSP_SOURCE latency=0  ! rtpbin ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video-x/raw,width=640,height=640 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! flvmux streamable=true ! rtmpsink  location=$RTMP_SERVER
```

The pipeline shows an error saying that **it could not link videoscale0 to x264enc0, neither element can handle caps video-x/raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)640**

Answer (score 1):

The media type should be `video/x-raw` and not `video-x/raw`.

Comment: It works, but camera's resolution is 1920x1080P, I set up video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720. It is frozen when video is played.